# Graylog Search with strings containing /

Tags: regex, search, graylog

I have logs which contains in full_message;

- -EndPoint:example/example/abc
- -EndPoint:example/example/qfdsf
- -EndPoint:example/example
- .. and so on

I am trying to write a search query to just get -EndPoint:example/example.

```
"-EndPoint:example/example" is not working
```

and I cant use "and" or "or" cause there hundreds of versions

Why and how can't/can I get only -EndPoint:example/example which doesn't have / at the end ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
"-EndPoint:example/example$"
```

It search for the string, making sure, it's the end of the string.

Comment: all of them are on the screen, still cant get only -EndPoint:example/example :(

Comment: Are you sure you search using regex and not a string?